# Modeling random variation from partial information

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization, random-variables

I am working on an optimization problem.

Let's say we have a grid of bins where solid metal cubes could be placed. We have a number of colored metal cubes to be arranged in the bins.

Each of these cubes weighs `1kg`. But the weight could change slightly over time due to natural phenomena and becomes `1kg + delta(x,y)`. We are interested in making sure the ratio between the total weight of one color to another remains same over time.

Observations say that `delta(x,y)` is not completely random. It can be thought of as `k0 + k1*x + k2*y + k3*x^2 + k4*y^2 + k5*x*y` where the constants `k0 k1 k2 ...` are unknown at the time of arranging the cubes. But in all cases `k0 > k1 > k3 > k5` and `k0 > k2 > k4 > k5` We can assume `k0/k1` as `c1`, `k1/k3` as `c2`... and `cn > 1` for all n. `k1` and `k2` are unrelated.

This observation lets us cancel out certain terms in `delta(x, y)` by arranging carefully. For example, if we arrange two red balls and two blue balls as `R B B R`, we can expect the linear terms to cancel.

Take for example a grid of `3x3`. Initially, we have the empty grid:

```
[ ]  [ ]  [ ]
[ ]  [ ]  [ ]
[ ]  [ ]  [ ]
```

and a number of metal cubes to be placed. As an example, let's say we are to arrange *one red cube*, *two blue cubes*, *four green cubes* and two dummy cubes.

Metal cubes to be placed:

```
1 x R
2 x B
4 x G
2 x *
```

One possible arrangement could be:

```
B * G
G R G
G * B
```

Given a set of values for c1, c2 etc, there is one arrangement that must be the best. I am trying to model a cost function which indicates the expected variation between the two colors. Then choose the arrangement that has minimum cost by iterating through all possible arrangement.

I am looking for some advice on how to model the expected variation between two colors.

Also, any advice on reducing the search space.

Comment: Shat are you defining $x$ and $y$ to be? The position of each cube? Please update your question.

Comment: Also your example has 4 x G in the answer but 3 x G in the definition..